# How do I bind TabControl ContextMenu Command?

Tags: wpf, templates, command, contextmenu

I've got the following data template I'm using for a TabControl.  Basically, it adds an X button to the tab so the user can close.  I'm wanting to add a context menu with several commands.  For now, I've just added a redundant Close item in the context menu.  But, when I execute this, my output window says "BindingExpression path error: 'CloseCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String' ...".  Binding the X button to the CloseCommand worked fine so I don't understand why it doesn't work for the context menu item.  Any ideas?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CloseableTabItemTemplate">
  <DockPanel Width="120">
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
            Content="X"/>
    <ContentPresenter
       Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center">

      <ContentPresenter.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
      </ContentPresenter.ContextMenu>
    </ContentPresenter>
  </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I ended up putting the context menu in the dock panel.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CloseableTabItemTemplate">
  <DockPanel Width="120">
      <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
      </DockPanel.ContextMenu>

    <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
            Content="X"/>
    <ContentPresenter
       Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center">

    </ContentPresenter>
  </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```